# Github Private Repo: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

So I am experiencing a really weird situation. Yesterday I created a private repo on a separate Github account. I added my SSH key to the account that account and then I made my first commit to that repo. So clearly I can commit to it. It even shows me as a a contributor.

However, today when I did it I get the error message:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I resolve this or troubleshoot it. I made sure the keys are in Github and in the ssh-agent. What else do I need to do?

**Update:**
I fixed this by adding myself as a collaborator to that account. Why didn't I need to do that before? This is now the new question so I am keeping it open for that.

Comment: If you get the `fatal: Could not read from remote repository` type `git remote -v` and it will show the remote repository that you're pushing/pulling to.  If it's not right then you can go to your .git folder and change the remotes in config file

Comment: Yes I did do that. I did see the correct remote servers.